# Django Query which join two models and find the average of scores

Tags: django, django-models, join

In my model there is some Tests in `Tests` model,

each test have some questions in it which are in `Question` model ,

and some types are relate to each test which are in `TestTypes` model  ,

and there is a `QuestionResult` model which save the scores of each test:

These are the models :

`Test` :

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    class DifficultyLevel(models.IntegerChoices):
        EASY = 1
        MEDIUM = 2
        HARD = 3

    types = models.ManyToManyField(
        'TestType',
        related_name='tests',
    )
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'question.Question',
        related_name='tests',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Standard tests could have multiple questions.',
    )


    level = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=DifficultyLevel.choices)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Question:

```
class Question(BaseModel):
  
    question_text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return truncatewords(self.question_text, 7)
```

TestResult :

```
class TestResult(BaseModel):
 
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(
        'Candidate',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='test_results',
    )

    test = models.ForeignKey(
        'exam.Test',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    test_score = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.candidate.user.email} - {self.test.title}'
```

TestType :

```
class TestType(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

now i want to get the score which each type earned

for example test1 got score =90 and test1 has two types : HTML and C++ .

Test2 got score = 50 and test2 has two types : HTML and Python

now i want to find the score which HTML type has got which should be (90+50)/2=70

how should i write the query ?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you as you need few subquery in your code

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Sum
```

Filter the Test objects by the type "HTML"

```
html_tests = Test.objects.filter(types__title='HTML')
```

Get the test_score field for each test that has the type "HTML"

```
html_scores = TestResult.objects.filter(test__in=html_tests).values('test_score')
```

Calculate the average score

```
average_score = html_scores.aggregate(Avg('test_score'))['test_score__avg']
```

Calculate the sum of the scores

```
total_score = html_scores.aggregate(Sum('test_score'))['test_score__sum']
```

Calculate the number of tests that have the type "HTML"

```
num_tests = html_tests.count()
```

Print the results

```
print(f'Average score: {average_score}')
print(f'Total score: {total_score}')
print(f'Number of tests: {num_tests}')
```

Comment: it does not return correct average . my data is : test1(type1,score:100) , test2(type2, score:20) , test12(type1,type2,type3,score:60) but the value it returns is: type_score": [
      {
        "title": "type1",
        "avg_score": 50
      },
      {
        "title": "type2 ",
        "avg_score": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "type3",
        "avg_score": 60
      }
    ]

Comment: i updated ans can you try once